# Xamarin.Forms loading Xaml with LoadFromXaml is not creating contained objects for a StackLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add to an existing xamarin.forms page, chunks of xaml that will be generated dynamically.

I'm starting my research using the [following example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/XAML/LoadRuntimeXAML) from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/runtime-load).

Everything works fine there, but when I try to change the string with the button def for a string with the stacklayout with the button inside, only the stacklayout is inflated, with no children at all.

That's weird, because you can inflate a full page in the example, but it looks like I'm missing something here.

Any advice about how to use LoadFromXaml for partial composite objects?

```
// MainPage.xaml.cs
void OnLoadButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string navigationButtonXAML = "<StackLayout><Button Text=\"Navigate\" /></StackLayout>";
            var sl = new StackLayout().LoadFromXaml(navigationButtonXAML);
            _stackLayout.Children.Add(sl);
        }
```

Comment: It seems `LoadFromXaml` not works for Layout . I will continue to check the solution for it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official doc, it's only using LoadFromXaml for single view or a complete contentPage, I also tried LoadFromXaml for layout, and it's loading the layout without its children. For loading layout with children, I'm try debugging with source code, will update later, and as a workaround, you can use layout with contentview like this:

```
string navigationStackLayoutXAML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ContentView xmlns=\"http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml\" xmlns:d=\"http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design\" xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" mc:Ignorable=\"d\" x:Class=\"LoadRuntimeXAML.CustomerViewDemo\"> <ContentView.Content> <StackLayout > <Label Text=\"Hello Xamarin.Forms!\" /> <Button Text=\"SECONDB\"/> </StackLayout> </ContentView.Content> </ContentView>";
ContentView contentView = new ContentView().LoadFromXaml(navigationStackLayoutXAML);
_stackLayout.Children.Add(contentView);
```

Although it's xaml is a little bit more complex, but it can use predefined attributes just as in .xaml, also, elements inside the contentView will be accessible through:

```
Button secondB = contentView.FindByName<Button>("secondB");
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the workaround would be to wrap the current xaml inside contentview tag?

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez I didn't have the luck to successfully debug Xamarin.Forms source code due to the changes in it's build file, pdb files not included in nuget build, so I can't step into the source code to investigate more. You can fire an issue in github(https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) about the LoadFromXaml to get clarifications.